# SQL select несколько значений в несколько строк

Tags: sql, db2

Есть таблица:

> NUMSUP    FAMPRO
>   15026507  157
>   15026508  157
>   15026508  215

Нужно выбрать `distinct numsup`, где `fampro` и `215`, и `157`:

```
select distinct NUMSUP from GESUPD 
where numsup in (15026508, 15026507) and FAMPRO = 157 and fampro = 215
```

Но я получаю пустой результат, а выборка должна показывать `15026508`.

Comment: `FAMPRO` для конкретной строки не может быть одновременно равно и `157`, и `215` - это бессмысленно.

Comment: Может, вам нужно `WHERE numsup IN (15026508, 15026507) AND fampro IN (157, 215)`?

Comment: @Regent Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky так был бы я уверен в том, что это то, что вообще нужно... Под текущую формулировку "`fampro` и `215`, и `157`" ответа не существует.

Answer (score 2):

```
select NUMSUP from GESUPD 
where fampro in (157, 215) 
group by NUMSUP having count(distinct FAMPRO) =2
```

или так

```
select NUMSUP from GESUPD where fampro =157
intersect
select NUMSUP from GESUPD where fampro =215
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса то: `select distinct NUMSUP from GESUPD where FAMPRO IN(157,215)`